# How can I insert the same record (duplicate) but with different ID in Apex?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to do this:

```
Interface__c interface = [SELECT Name, Id, Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Interface__c where Name LIKE :'name'];
insert interface;
```

And by the same record I mean record with the same one field (but it must have other fields too because they are required.

Comment: Do you mean you want to clone the record? Check out Sobject clone method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is just if you trying a single record for multiple you need to a list and assign values.

```
Interface__c interface = [SELECT Name, Id, Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Interface__c where Name LIKE :'name'];
Interface__c obj= new interface__c();
obj.filed1___c= interface.Field1__c;
obj.Name=interface.Name;
.
.
.
Insert obj;
```

Just note not to assign Id please.

OR

`insert interface.deepClone();`

**Note: You can also use clone and deepclone**

[Clone with all fields](https://sfdcera.com/apex-code-to-clone-a-record-with-all-fields/)

[Clone vs DeepClone](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/08/difference-between-clone-and-deepclone.html)